# Resteasy not working with @ApplicationPath

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I am not being able to get JAX-RS working with Resteasy 2.3.5 usingh simple @ApplicationPath annotation. Here is the code I am using:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    s.add(ViewController.class);
    return s;
  }
}

@Path("/")
public class ViewController {
  @GET
  @Path("/test")
  public String test() {
    return "Yes!";
  }
}
```

Requesting on "/uri-context/rest/test/" throws a 404. Using Jersey everything works seamlessly. Since this is a very trivial part of JAX-RS what's going on wrong?

Currently I am using only 4 libs of Resteasy that I would require:

- async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.5.Final.jar
- jaxrs-api-2.3.5.Final.jar
- resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar
- scannotation-1.0.3.jar

Nevertheless, putting all the libs (except for resteasy-cdi-2.3.5.Final.jar), also does not solve the problem.

Comment: You say using Jersey it works, but you don't say what you are trying to use instead of Jersey where it doesn't work.

Comment: It's the basic URL/URI calling.

Comment: Have you done the proper configuration as per [RESTEasy Installation Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#Installation_Configuration) ? Can you describe your setup (application server, web.xml, etc) some more ?

Answer (score 3):

Beware with **Jax-RS** 1.0, the **path** and the **slash**

```
@ApplicationPath("api") //NO slash
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}

@Path("/users")  // YES slash
public class ViewController {

  @GET
  @Path("all") //NO slash
  public String all() {
    return "Yes!";
  }
}
```

Usually taking care of slashes makes it quickly better.

---

UPDATE for JAX-RS 2 :

In JAX-RS 2, the spec DOES says that leading and trailing slashes in `@ApplicationPath` or `@Path` will be ignored.

```
(3)If the resource class URI template does not end with a ‘/’ character
then one is added during the concatenation.
```

For what I have tested with Jersey 2 and Resteasy, this is now respected.

Comment: You sir, a my hero! I had a slash in front of the path of my method. This is all very fuzzy to me when to use a slash or not...

Comment: Oh, kill me, kill me now.