# Simple REST service with Path Annotations - 404 Error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jboss, jax-rs

What do I need to make this minimalist REST Example work ?

Projet Name : hello-rest

App Code :

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyJAXWSApp extends Application {
}
```

MessageResource :

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("message")
    public class MessageResource {
    @GET
    public String Hello() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

MAVEN config :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Problem :** 
So far, Deployment via Eclipse Neon in WildFly 10x results in 404 error when I call Service URI :

```
http://localhost:8080/hello-rest/resources/message
```

Source : [Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_rest_endpoint)

**PS :** Server Deployment OK :

> 22:20:04,486 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
>   ...
>
> 22:20:04,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
>   ...
>
> 22:20:04,974 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
>   ....
>
> 22:20:06,992 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class JAXRSConfiguration
>   ...
>
> 22:20:07,074 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> 22:20:07,135 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I see in your server output is it registered the path as "/hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT". So until you change your Maven config to not append the version to your war you'll have to add "-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" to your URL when calling the service.

i.e. `http://localhost:8080/hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resources/message`

I've also always seen the ApplicationPath and Path annotations on resources (not methods) as starting with '/'. I'm not sure if it's required or not but I'd recommend it as a best practice regardless.

UPDATE: Looked it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26100548/1495050) and as of JAX-RS 2 the trailing and leading slashes should not be required.

Comment: I am extremely grateful to you Daniel. The maven version appending was the culprit. I've been going crazy for hours. I had totally lost hindsight. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. That's one of those things you don't notice until you've hit it a few times.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have this in your `MyJAXWSApp` ?

```
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(your.package.name.MessageResource.class);
}
```

**Note**: Make sure the package is correct.  I've just put `your.package.name` as an example, but you'll need to provide the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Per 29.2.7.1 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#GILIK) he shouldn't have to:
"By default, all the resources in an archive will be processed for resources."

Comment: Acording to Oracle Doc this is not necessary. But I did try it though, with no noticeable effect.

Comment: I noticed in your Wildfly logs that your web context is **/hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**.  So you might want to try **http://localhost:8080/hello-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resources/message**